# android unable to scroll image with ViewPager --> ScrollView --> Imageview

Tags: android, layout, imageview, scrollview, android-viewpager

I am using a view pager inside my main view. Depending on the content of the frames I add one of two xml files. The first one is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">        

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="6dip">   

        <!-- header -THIS is the source of the problem! -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView            
                android:textSize="32dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- content -->
       <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fillViewport="true">

           <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


        </ScrollView>


        <!-- footer -->

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Expires on..."
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The alternative xml file is identical apart from the fact that the scrollview's child is an ImageView instead of a TextView.

Now, when using the textview all works fine. I can make use of the scrollview to scroll the text in the view up and down. However, when I use the layout with the imageview the image is frozen and the scrollview does not move it up and down.

Does anybody have any idea why this is??

Comment: Just make your control with - `ScrollView -> ViewPager -> ImageView`

Comment: That wont work. I need the image to be fully enclosed inside the viewpager